Movie from before the early 80's about a mother and son trying to hide in the mountains from killers
I'm looking for a movie that starts with showing the dad, dark hair, putting his (maybe 5 or 6 yr old) son in bed for the night. The son is playing with his robot. It shows the mom, who has kind of short, blonde hair, in the garage sculpting something. Then shows 3 or 4 heavily armed, masked men bursting through the son's bedroom door, the dad dives over his son, and they shoot and kill him. The gunmen leave, the mom comes in grabs the boy (who is clinging to his robot).
And the whole movie is about her trying to hide from the people that killed her husband. She doesn't know why they are after her but she stays on the run with her son.
In the end, she goes to her father, who lives in the mountains. She feels somewhat safe til she discovers a micro something or other in her sons robot (put there by her husband) and she knows they will keep coming for her because it has a tracking device. Her dad booby traps the whole area. The only access to his place is to cross a hanging bridge. They eventually find her. They come for her in the night they battle and she wins. I used to think it was called "Nowhere to Hide" but now I can't find it anywhere.

Welcome to Movies & TV!  What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.
